# wp8 on first launch

Tags: windows-phone-8, isolatedstorage

I'm writing a wp8 application and I want a page to load up the first time the app is launched and after that it never appears again, I have been googling for a very long time now and still cant get my head around it, I am only a beginner at this stage and still learning. I no I will need to use isolated storage for this but trying to implement it is a different story. Any help would be very much appreciated. I'm not asking anyone to do it for me, I'm just asking for a bit of guidance.

Comment: Hi, You want to show the page only once after installing the application?

Comment: yes like instructions and after they move onto the next page, once they load the app again, the instructions page will not appear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for the guidance - as you have mentioned IsolatedStorage would be suitable here. In fact [IsolatedSotorageSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj714090%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) will be easiest I think here.

So when your App launches you should determine if it's the first run or not.
You can for example in `App.xaml.cs` modify method Application_Launching, so that it will check if specific key in IsolatedStorageSettings exists if not - it means its the first run ans set up a flag.

After you know if it's the first run (or not) you can try to redirect the Navigation. I think it's well explained [on this blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ptorr/archive/2010/08/28/redirecting-an-initial-navigation.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0).

You can also try to redirect from MainPage in Loaded event (in this case you can see a blink of MainPage) - it depends what do you want to achieve.

Other way may be - not to Navigate to specific Page - but to change MainPage content, depending on your flag (if it's the very first run).

Comment: I'm having an issue with the code, It isn't going to the next page when the app is launched the 2nd time, what could be the issue

Comment: @GinaByrne It's hard to say, there can be many reasons. Have you looked at the blog I've mentioned? You have to care only for MainPage and only when you check for the first run (IsolatedStorageSettings). And probably you should also unsubscribe from RootFrame.Navigating before you jump to your FirstLaunchPage. Otherwise it will be fired every time you Navigate.

Comment: I have been looking at it trying to integrate some of the features in the blog into mine, but still no luck, why is this such a hard thing to do, you would think they would make it easier

Comment: @GinaByrne It's no so hard when you understand how it works. I've managed to do what you want, but try to do it yourself :) One clue is that you should use Dispatcher (as in blog), otherwise it won't Navigate. Unfortunately I don't have more time today, but if you hadn't succeeded - give me a sign.

Comment: I am trying to figure it out, i have spent to many hours at it this stage and the only way to learn is by doing, If i am still stuck at this, tomorrow I will give you a sign, thanks for your help, I really do appreciate it :)

Comment: I regret to say that I am still stuck on that piece, feeling like giving up on the first launch. :(

Comment: @GinaByrne Ok - so tell what is now the main problem - what happens? Were you able to show firstLaunch? Is it possible that you send me code?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to launch any page only once after installing the application, you can do so on application launch:

```
  private void Application_Launching(object sender, LaunchingEventArgs e)
    {
        IsolatedStorageSettings settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
        if (IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains("IsFirstTimeLaunched") && settings["IsFirstTimeLaunched"] == "true")
        {                   

            Uri nUri = new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
            RootFrame.Navigate(nUri);       
        }
        else
        {   settings["IsFirstTimeLaunched"] = "true" ;
            settings.Save();
            Uri nUri = new Uri("/FirstTimeLaunch.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
            RootFrame.Navigate(nUri);
        }           
    }
```

You can delete also this from inside the app also if at any point of time you want the FirstTimeLaunch page again, Suppose in every 30 days you want to show the instructions again on launch.

Comment: It will be also useful to Save() IsolatedStorageSettings.

Comment: @GinaByrne , vasuy19: I'm afraid that your code won't Navigate every time to FirstTimeLaunch - you are not cancelling the Navigation to MainPage. As I've tested it there may be some problems. Try to redirect in RootFrame.Navigating event.

Comment: yes, I am experiencing, some problems, it only loads the mainpage, never goes to the first, just goes to the main

Answer (score 0):

Call this method inside MainPage.xaml.cs after APP load

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
        if (!App.ViewModel.IsDataLoaded)
        {
            App.ViewModel.LoadData();                
        }

        IsolatedStorageSettings settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
        if (IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains("IsFirstTimeLaunched") && (string)settings["IsFirstTimeLaunched"] == "true")
        {

            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));                
        }
        else
        {
            settings["IsFirstTimeLaunched"] = "true";
            settings.Save();
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/FirstLaunch.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        }           
}
```